# Fancybox is not showing the fancybox-title as it should (wordpress theme)

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, plugins, fancybox

I'm trying to fix a template which was modified long time ago. The problem is that it doesn't show the fancybox title (or description) anymore, under the image.

All the links are here (I need 10 reputation to post 3 links sorry) http://pastebin.com/0eHsVA62

I really can't find the problem.

don't see what in the original theme is called fancybox-title. here a png of what I see instead. http://i1.minus.com/iHeb9GFZXzpqi.png

```
<span id="fancybox-title-wrap">
<span id="fancybox-title-left">
</span>
<span id="fancybox-title-main">Title example</span>
<span id="fancybox-title-right">
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: If you want titles in fancybox, your anchors need to have the `title` attribute like `<a title="this is the title" href="xxx.jpg" rel="gallery">`

Comment: yeah I know, the problem is how to find it inside the **template** and how to fix it in order to make it works
It's not an html problem
maybe is more a php/javascript problem

Answer (score 0):

Since this is wordpress and i cant see 100% where it needs to be, im going to assume that the "Fancybox" is a plugin and not hard coded. Since it needs the "title" attr to display a title under the picture then, via wordpress go to the post or page and then edit it. Inside the post/page, hover over the image until you see the mini edit picture icon. Click it and edit the image. Somewhere in there (depending on the theme version and wordpress version) will be a title section to fill. Enter it there and you should be good to go.

If its a gallery then the same thing applies.

If its a gallery provided by another plugin and fancybox provides the lightbox functionality only then, again, somewhere within the plugin will be a title or caption box etc...edit that and you should be good to go.

hope this helps.